# How does this query work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table `Name`:

```
+-------+
| Name  |
+-------+
|  red  |
|  black|
| white |
| green |
| orange|
+--------+
```

Output will return the pair (where permutation wont be allowed, e.g. black,red and red,black)

My SQL Server query:

```
select  
    A, B 
from
    (select 
         A.colorname A, B.colorname B 
     from 
         colors A  
     join 
         colors B on A.colorname <> B.colorname
                  and A.colorname < B.colorname) C
```

My question is: how is this query working?

I am not getting the way `A.colorname < B.colorname` working here...and the thing is, removing `A.colorname<>B.colorname` is returning the same result.

Comment: the `A.colorname < B.colorname` prevents the permutation by always listing the result in alphabetical order.

Comment: `A.colorname<>B.colorname` is a subset of `A.colorname < B.colorname` so removing it wouldn't affect the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in your table are all different and can always be sorted alphabetically.

By joining the table with `<` comparison, it would always give your resulted rows by joining the row on left, to the rows which has a 'greater' value on right.

```
+-------+   +-------+
| Name  |   | Name  |   
+-------+   +-------+
| red   |   | red   |
+-------+   +-------+
| black |   | black |
+-------+   +-------+
| white |   | white |
+-------+   +-------+
| green |   | green |
+-------+   +-------+
| orange|   | orange|
+-------+   +-------+
```

Starting from first row on LEFT table, result from `JOIN` is

```
red - white
```

Then on the second row, result from `JOIN` is

```
black - red
black - white
black - green
black - orange
```

On the third row, as there's nothing greater than `white` that would yield empty result.

The same logic you can work out the remaining results.

As a result, it will show all pairs without permutation.

Note `A.colorname<>B.colorname` is not necessary as it's just a subset of `A.colorname < B.colorname`.

Answer (score 1):

`A.colorname < B.colorname` 
gives you result in an alphabetical order. A permutation of two colors is picked only once. For e.g. black and red has two permutations:

1. black,red
2. red,black.

Only the first one is picked because name of colors is in alphabetical order.